# How to move data members of an object?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Imagine that we got an object passed to a function and would like move semantics to be applied to its individual members. Which option to choose: call `std::move` on each member or move the whole object (several times) and then access its members as rvalues?

```cpp
Foo::Foo(Object object)
// this way?
: member1(std::move(object.member1)), member2(std::move(object.member2)) {} 
// or this way?
: member2(std::move(object).member2), member2(std::move(object).member2) {}
```

To be more specific, consider the following example. There is a downloader class which accepts connection parameters as an object. I want to move-assign its members to the members of the downloader, so I'm doing the following:

```cpp
class ConnectionParameters
{
public:
    ConnectionParameters(string server, string login, string password, unsigned short port, unsigned int connectionLimit, unsigned long long speedLimit)
        : server(move(server))
        , login(move(login))
        , password(move(password))
        , port(port)
        , connectionLimit(connectionLimit)
        , speedLimit(speedLimit) {}

    ConnectionParameters(const ConnectionParameters &) = delete;    // disable copy constructor
    ConnectionParameters(ConnectionParameters &&) = default;    // default move constructor

    const string & getServer() const & { return this->server; }
    string && getServer() && { return move(this->server); }

    const string & getLogin() const & { return this->login; }
    string && getLogin() && { return move(this->login); }

    const string & getPassword() const & { return this->password; }
    string && getPassword() && { return move(this->password); }

    unsigned short getPort() const  { return this->port; }
    unsigned int getConnectionLimit() const { return this->connectionLimit; }
    unsigned long long getSpeedLimit() const { return this->speedLimit; }

private:
    string server, login, password;
    unsigned short port;
    unsigned int connectionLimit;
    unsigned long long speedLimit;
};

class Downloader
{
public:
    Downloader(ConnectionParameters connectionParameters, string downloadDirectory, unsigned long long diskSpaceMinimum)
        : server(move(connectionParameters).getServer()) // 1st move
        , login(move(connectionParameters).getLogin()) // 2nd move!
        , password(move(connectionParameters).getPassword()) // 3rd move!
        , port(connectionParameters.getPort())
        , connectionLimit(connectionParameters.getConnectionLimit())
        , speedLimit(connectionParameters.getSpeedLimit())
        , downloadDirectory(move(downloadDirectory))
        , diskSpaceMinimum(diskSpaceMinimum) {}

private:
    string server, login, password;
    unsigned short port;
    unsigned int connectionLimit;
    unsigned long long speedLimit;
    string downloadDirectory;
    unsigned long long diskSpaceMinimum;
};
```

What I don't like in this approach is that `std::move` is called several times on the same `connectionParameters` object. Although it works, it probably violates the principle of move semantics (that the object can't be used after being moved).

An alternative approach would be to move members individually:

```cpp
struct ConnectionParameters
{
    string server, login, password;
    unsigned short port;
    unsigned int connectionLimit;
    unsigned long long speedLimit;

    ConnectionParameters(string server, string login, string password, unsigned short port, unsigned int connectionLimit, unsigned long long speedLimit)
        : server(move(server))
        , login(move(login))
        , password(move(password))
        , port(port)
        , connectionLimit(connectionLimit)
        , speedLimit(speedLimit) {}

    ConnectionParameters(const ConnectionParameters &) = delete;    // disable copy constructor
    ConnectionParameters(ConnectionParameters &&) = default;    // default move constructor
};

class Downloader
{
public:
    Downloader(ConnectionParameters connectionParameters, string downloadDirectory, unsigned long long diskSpaceMinimum)
        : server(move(connectionParameters.server))
        , login(move(connectionParameters.login))
        , password(move(connectionParameters.password))
        , port(connectionParameters.port)
        , connectionLimit(connectionParameters.connectionLimit)
        , speedLimit(connectionParameters.speedLimit)
        , downloadDirectory(move(downloadDirectory))
        , diskSpaceMinimum(diskSpaceMinimum) {}

private:
    string server, login, password;
    unsigned short port;
    unsigned int connectionLimit;
    unsigned long long speedLimit;
    string downloadDirectory;
    unsigned long long diskSpaceMinimum;
};
```

What I don't like here is that members of the `ConnectionParameters` structure are directly exposed (otherwise, `Downloader` would not be able to move them).

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: A note: move semantics are essentially wasted if operating on an object copy. Consider passing rvalue-references to the constructors instead of object copies.

Comment: Well, I partially agree. However, it seems to be a common practice as long as the object passed has a move constructor. Rvalue reference won't allow it to accept copies (just in case you don't really want to move what is passed).