# How to (properly) move non-static data members?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Let’s say I have a class with a non-static data member that’s worthy to be moved, e.g. a `std::vector`. When I write a get accessor to it, using ref qualifiers, I can distinguish between lvalue and rvalue of the class object. In the lvalue case, I’ll copy the member, but in the rvalue case, I’d move it. For this, I have seen two syntaxes tagged `A` and `B` in the following snippet:

```cpp
class C
{
    std::vector<int> m_values;
public:
    std::vector<int> values() const &;
    std::vector<int> values() &&
    {
        return std::move(m_values); // A
        return std::move(*this).m_values; // B
    }
};
```

I tested both and they both move the value. I get why one would use `A`, it’s plain obvious what’s intended. I find `B` weird, so why do people use it? What are the advantages?

The answers to the following questions contain no answer to my question:

- [How to move data members of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817760/how-to-move-data-members-of-an-object)
- [What is `std::move()`, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: who is "people" that use it? where did you see it?

Comment: For completeness, have you tried `return m_values`?

Comment: B relies on a core language rule that makes `forward<S>(s).mem` behave usefully. You have no more reason to use B than to use `this` artificially.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I have definitely seen it in examples. Syntax stuff like that is hard to google. I’ve put `std::move(*this).m_` in GitHub and it has hits. (This is irrelevant to the question.) Note that this only gets examples using a specific naming pattern. `std::move(*this).` gives a lot of “false positives” with function calls. They are similar, but not the same.

Comment: @YSC, why would I? It does not move. This evidenced by using a non-copyable type like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Maybe they need to do `std::move(*this).memberFunc()` somewhere else and just want to be consistent.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Not a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I find `B` weird, so why do people use it?

I can only speculate but I assume that people using it don't find it weird.

> What are the advantages?

None - except for readability for people who like it better than `std::move(m_values)`.

Comment: Having reference as instance data is not good practice. But in case of such design, A would probably cause UB by changing the reference type, while B keeps it consistent. If this is in template code, be 1M% cautious.

Comment: @Red.Wave I agree that keeping references as members aren't usually a good thing but using `std::move` on one shouldn't present any problems afaik. It'll just be moving from the referenced object - but perhaps the fact that it _won't_ move if `std::move(obj).refmember` is used is reason enough to use that form.

Comment: You caught up to me, in the last sentence. If you have prvalue of a type with a member of lvalue reference type, then moving the member is most probably going to break your programs logic; a move happens where a copy was intended, and source object will be left defaulted/null/empty. The problem with using references as instance members is risk of dangling. When pointers are used, you know you must keep track of them. With references, there's more subtle caveats. e.g `std::tuple::tuple` discards rvalue to const lvalue binding if the result is supposed to be stored as const lvalue reference.